# Jquery hide and show functions

Tags: jquery, function, click, hide, show

On my header.php (included in all my pages because there's the menu inside), I made this function which shows/hides a #fullscreen-slider and which changes by the way the color of my #logo which is set to white when slider is on and black when it is off.

I would like this text to be initially white on my homepage and black on all the others.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#logo a').css('color','white');
$('#logo').click(function(event) {

    if ($('#fullscreen-slider').is(':visible')) {

        $('#fullscreen-slider').hide();
        $('#logo a').css('color','black');

    } else {

        $('#fullscreen-slider').show();
        $('#logo a').css('color','white');

    }

    event.preventDefault();

});
});
```

I also added this function on all pages excepted the homepage :

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('#fullscreen-slider').hide();
$('#logo a').css('color','#333');
});
</script>
```

Here is the html :

```
<body>
<div id="conteneur">
<div id="fullscreen-slider" class="royalSlider rsDefault">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/perron_01.jpg" />
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/perron_01.jpg" />
    </div>
    <header>
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="#">Adequat</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your default colour is white, set this within your CSS.

```
#logo a {
color: #white;
}
```

Make sure to cache your elements so you're not constantly hitting the DOM like so:

```
var logoAnchor = $('#logo a'),
    logo = $('#logo'),
    fullscreenSlider = $('#fullscreen-slider');
```

I'm assuming that your logo anchor is within #fullscreen-slider? if so then you'll need to traverse because jQuery can't find the element you're targeting. If not then try this:

```
logoAnchor.click(function(event) {

    if ($(fullscreenSlider).is(':visible')) {
        $this.hide();
        logoAnchor.css('color','black');
    } else {
        $this.show();
        logoAnchor.css('color','white');
    }

});
```

Can you please paste in your HTML into your question.

Comment: My default color is black on all pages, and when the fullscreenslider is on. As my fullscreenslider is on at homepage, the logo is white in the first place. For the moment I kept this function and I added another to hide automatically the fullscreenslider on other pages and one to keep the logo in black.

Comment: So given your html structure - you are clicking on the anchor, jQuery cannot find fullslider within #logo. You need to traverse up the DOM, read this: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 0):

> I would like this text to be initially white on my homepage and black on all the others.

I would achieve this checking the actual url. Either using PHP or js.

Using js [`document.location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) and assuming that you know the url of your home page (eg.: `www.your-domain.com/index.php` will return `/index.php` while `www.your-domain.com/` will return `/`)

```
var logoColor = 'black';
if (document.location.pathname.indexOf("index.php") != 0 ||
    document.location.pathname == '/') {
    logoColor = 'white';
}
// ...
$('#logo a').css('color', logoColor);
```

Using PHP:

In **index.php**, before you include **header.php** add following:

```
<?php $logoColor = 'white'; ?>
```

Then in **header.php**:

```
// ...
$('#logo a').css('color', '<?php echo isset($logoColor) ? $logoColor : 'black' ; ?>');
// ...
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know yet the adress of my homepage !

Comment: @AdrienQuélet . So use PHP, as in my example. Just add that php script before you render the home page (and header.php). I guess you should know which **file**.php is rendering your homepage?

Comment: I think I will die if I try something more. It has been 1 week that I didn't sleep. Would you be able to help me for that if I send you the files ? I know it not very usual but I am loosing all my faith...and I am really a beginner.